# clicking the sym button does not bring up the symbol popup

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I have an EditField in my program. whenever i press the 'sym' key on the keypad the menu comes up instead of the usual symbol page.  I am not using keyode method.
My program only has a trackwheel click which handles button clicks.

```
protected boolean trackwheelClick(int status, int time) {

    if(_remMefld.isFocus()){

        if(!remeberMe){
            _remMefld.setBitmap(_selectCheckbox);   
            remeberMe = true;                  
        }
        else{
            _remMefld.setBitmap(_deselectCheckbox);   
            remeberMe = false;                 
        }

    }

    return super.trackwheelClick(status, time);  
}
```

what could be the reason? 
Am i missing something??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the answer and will write it down..just in case...

i had both makeMenu and keyControl methods. 
remove keycontrol and sym will work perfectly.